# iPhone 4S logic board replacement

Tags: hardware, iphone

I have damaged my iPhone 4S. A weight was dropped on it and it stopped working instantly. I've opened the back and it appears the bottom of the battery, the speaker and charger point have been damaged. All at the bottom of the phone. The logic board appears fine.

Is it possible to put this into another iPhone 4S and thereafter access all my files, music, photos etc.? Stupidly it hasn't been backed up and there are many things I don't want to lose.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Also if it is just a straight swap over, do I need to get a replacement with equivalent memory?

Comment: If I were you I'd take it to an Apple Store and ask.

Comment: Yes thanks I did take it there and they seemed unsure themselves. They only seemed to be concerned that they got their message across that they wouldn't advise it as it would invalidate warranty. The phone is totally ruined so that really doesn't matter. Oh well thanks for advise I will try and if anyone else is keen to find out results I will post on here afterwards

Comment: Yes it worked. I purchased a 4s from eBay, removed the logic board and replaced it with the one from my damaged phone. Turned it on and my phone was back. I've just purchased the 20gb iCloud data and am backing up as we speak. Hope this may help somebody in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I purchased another iPhone 4S, removed the logic board and replaced it with the one from my damaged phone. The damaged phone was 32gb and the replacement model was only 16gb. I figured this wouldn't matter as the memory is attached to the logic board itself so as this was being removed I bought the cheapest replacement available. The repair is fairly straight forward and is much easier than replacing the glass screen which I've had to do on a number of occasions for friends. There are many links on YouTube which are perfect to follow. I have subsequently purchased iCloud data to avoid the worry of something like this happening again. I think I was fortunate to have not damaged the logic board otherwise this repair/replacement wouldn't have been possible.